# GIMP running but cannot view display

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, xfce, gimp

In ubuntu, I am launching GIMP from command line like this:

```
user@l1d:~$ /usr/bin/gimp
```

Now instead of GIMP launching and showing its GUI display, the command just hangs. Opening another terminal I see the following:

```
user@l1d:~$ ps aux | grep gimp
user    2804  0.0  0.1 289956 22040 tty1     Sl   Aug17   0:00 gimp-2.8 /home/user/Downloads/xtreme.png
user   25888  0.0  0.1 289956 22408 tty1     Sl   Aug17   0:00 gimp-2.8 /mnt/2/backup2/Users/User/Desktop/im/avatar.png
user   28428  0.1  0.1 289976 21820 tty1     Sl   12:32   0:00 gimp-2.8
user   28532  0.1  0.1 289972 21992 pts/13   Sl+  12:33   0:00 gimp
user   28959  3.0  0.1 289976 21856 tty1     Sl   12:36   0:00 gimp-2.8
user   28965  5.1  0.1 289976 22132 pts/14   Sl+  12:36   0:00 /usr/bin/gimp
user   28980  0.0  0.0   9648   936 pts/20   S+   12:36   0:00 grep gimp
```

As you can see GIMP is running but for some reason the GUI is not showing. I have gone through all different workspaces, ALT+Tab  etc   but I still cannot find the window.

Also I have checked in Display and there is only 1 monitor listed, so it couldn't be hiding on another monitor.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Find your Gimp profile (normally ~/.gimp-2.8), and try, in that order, to:

- erase the sessionrc file in it (this is where Gimp remember Window positions)
- if this is not enough, rename the whole profile (`.gimp-2.8` -> `.gimp-2.8.disabled` for instance). Gimp will create a new profile and if things are OK, you can later copy things back if needed (brushes, patterns...).

Otherwise start Gimp with `gimp --verbose` to make it tell us what it is doing.